# SwiftUI - Add values from two textfields using var or let

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

How to add values of two textfields in SwiftUI?

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value1 = ""
    @State private var value2 = ""
    
    private var sumValues = (Int(value1) ?? 0) + (Int(value2) ?? 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("type value 1 here", text: $value1)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            
            TextField("type value 2 here", text: $value2)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            
            Text("sum: \(sumValues)")
            
            // I need to have a var or let, so I cannot use something like this:
            //Text("sum: \((Int(value1) ?? 0) + (Int(value2) ?? 0))")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on line with **private var sumValues...**:

> Cannot use instance member 'value1' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available
>
> Cannot use instance member 'value2' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `computed-property`.

```
private var sumValues: Int { (Int(value1) ?? 0) + (Int(value2) ?? 0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible approach is to move all this logic (and might be all other) into view model, like below - so keep engine separated of view and let standard observed dynamic property take care of view updates:

Here is simple demo. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
class CalcViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value1 = "" {
        didSet { update() }
    }
    @Published var value2 = "" {
        didSet { update() }
    }
    @Published var sum: Int = 0

    private func update() {
        self.sum = (Int(value1) ?? 0) + (Int(value2) ?? 0)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = CalcViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("type value 1 here", text: $vm.value1)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)

            TextField("type value 2 here", text: $vm.value2)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)

            Text("sum: \(vm.sum)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Try setting a value for one field, then removing it, then adding it again (`+=` will be executed every time -> `sum` will never be cleared).

Comment: Ok.. the intention was to show only approach... and corrected to make it calculator. Thanks @pawello2222.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change `sumValues` to a computed property:

```
private var sumValues: Int {
        get {
            (Int(value1) ?? 0) + (Int(value2) ?? 0)
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need `get` - look at @Frankenstein's answer.

Comment: @pawello2222 Isn't this answer correct as well? I have read somewhere that we don't need to write get when we just use get and not set. But isn't it still a valid answer? Because I have tested it and it works.

Comment: @mallow Yes, it is valid (and I upvoted it as well). The now accepted solution is just *cleaner*.